# Get db docs with a certain value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am trying to get all of the posts that are listed under a group (essentially the topic of a post). Each post document has a field called group_id, which contains the id of the groups document. When I try to search for the posts that contain a specific group_id (given via a link parameter) using the following code, it returns every post in the db, even though they are not listed under the group.

Backend:

```
const getGroupPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const group_id = req.params.id

  const posts = await Post.find({group_id}).sort({createdAt: -1})

  res.status(200).json(posts)
}
```

---

Frontend:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/posts/group/${params.groupId}`, {
        headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`},
      })
      const json = await response.json()

      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({type: 'SET_POSTS', payload: json})
      }
    }

    if (user) {
      fetchPosts()
    }
  }, [dispatch, user])
```

---

I am fairly certain that this is an issue with my backend code as I have the same issue when I use postman, although maybe I need to declare another header(?). All help appreciated!

Comment: Did you verify that `const group_id = req.params.id` has the value that you are passing from frontend? Since you have used different variables like `id`, `groupId` and `group_id` for same thing I doubt if the value is passed to MongoDB.

Comment: Are you using mongoose? If so, does your schema have a field named `group_id`? The spelling needs to be the same.

Comment: @heyitsvajid the value is passed properly. The issue was the schema - thanks for all of your suggestions!